# Honeywell T9 won't work on Trane System

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I attached all the wires to the correct colors, but the thermostat would not power up.  So I reinstalled the old basic thermostat and it worked. A few days later I looked at my photo of the wiring and I had placed the white wire on the W2 instead of W1.  So I reinstalled the T9 with this correction and again the T9 would not power on.

I have photos of the system board and the thermostat connections (T9 and old one).

https://photos.app.goo.gl/BVPF6u6a7GAriQbL6

Let me know if I made an obvious mistake with the wiring.